# Working on separate bookchapters with R Markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Suppose I am writing a document with the following layout:

```
Ch1
  Ch1.1
Ch2
...
```

where `Ch` stands for some chapter in the document.

Each `Ch` is a separate file, for example `Ch1.1.rmd`. There is one file `main.rmd` which has the following structure:

````
```{r child='Ch1.rmd'}
```
```{r child='Ch1.1.rmd'}
```
```{r child='Ch2.rmd'}
```
...
````

If I compile `main.rmd` I get the whole document, which works great.

But I work on separate chapters at a time, and don't want to compile the whole document each time to see the result. The problem is that there are dependencies. `Ch1.1.rmd` uses functions defined in `Ch1.rmd`, so it doesn't compile on itself.

*What are efficient ways to work on _separate_ chapters with dependencies to others while keeping the document (and possibly dependency) structure _in one place_?*

Note: putting functions in a separate file, and loading it prior to compilation of each chapter is not an option since all functions/variables are inline with text.

Comment: I ran into an R package for writing books a few days back. https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/  I did not really follow it closely because right now I don't have that much use, but it does seem to offer something like what you want -- https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html .

Comment: @R.S. Thanks. This seems to be one possible answer, so if you want, you can convert it to one. You'll certainly get one upvote :)

Comment: Well, I guess this one was too easy. I hardly can offer any hands down info on the package. So  I can live happily with the +1 you gave above :-)  Thanks for the offer .

Comment: Put your functions in a package which gets loaded while knitting.

Comment: @drmariod, the functions are defined inline with text in each chapter.

Answer (score 2):

You might use the caching options in `knitr` and the `dependson` argument.

Your example would be:

`{r Ch1, child='Ch1.rmd', cache=TRUE}`

    `{r child='Ch1.1.rmd', dependson='Ch1'}`

    `{r child='Ch2.rmd'}`

Comment: And how would you compile only `Ch1.1`?

Comment: Oops, I think I misunderstood your problem: I thought that you did not want to recompile the Ch1 chunk. Obviously, my answer is not valid. In your case, I would put all the functions in separate R script or package and load it at the start of each rmd file...

Comment: No problem. The answer does give a nice way to omit recompiling R-code. Still the whole tex code is recompiled. Note that one could also use `cache=TRUE, autodep=TRUE`.